# Basic HTTP Client Code from MSDN failing to fetch result

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application, httpclient

I am trying to Run a simple Msdn Article of HttpClient Class :
[Create Http Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0) in .Net Core Console Application.

Unfortunately its not working at all and exiting application.

[image]

Nothing in Output , Just getting blown on client Call.

Comment: Please show code as *text* rather than as screenshots... it makes it a lot easier for people to try the code themselves. In this particular case it's easy enough to see what's wrong without trying the code ourselves, but fundamentally both the code and the console output are text, so please *show* them as text.

Comment: omg @JonSkeet Message, It's real?  or just a bot replying as mediator.

Comment: Very much real - and I hope you take my advice to heart.

Answer (score 6):

You're calling a `Task`, meaning, it runs asynchronous and in this context your application quits before its able to output the result.

To overcome this, you'll need to await the `NewMethod` call.

```
static async Task Main(string [] args)
{
    await NewMethod();
}
```

Comment: It's a silly mistake of async-await which I ignored. ahh, Thanks buddy